# Identityserver4 user management when only external users are needed

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4

My scenario: I have a client ASP.NET MVC app that I'm now securing with IdentityServer4, using IDSRV4 only as Federated Gateway (no local users are needed). i.e. any user accessing the app can only authenticate using an external provider (either ADFS for our internal company users or the Belgian eID login provider via SAML2 for external users which are all Belgian citizens). IDSRV4 returns the external claims to the client app (using the OpenIDConnect OWIN middleware), which is then used to sign in the user.

This flow is working in terms of authentication (i.e. identitytoken). However I'm a bit confused if I will need a persistent user store on my IDSRV4 (like ASP.NET Core Identity) if I want to start requesting access tokens, or if I could just keep on living with InMemory users (or even no store at all) as ALL my users will ALWAYS be identified by one of the two aforementioned external providers.

Thanks for any insight.

Mathieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need any persistent user store for the purpose of handing out access tokens, 
that is handled by Identity Server. The configuration of the client application in IdentityServer needs to use the hybrid flow (AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid) and the client application's has to request an authorization code as well as an identity token (options.ResponseType = "code id_token").

However, it may not be a best practice to pass the unique identification of users (subject claim or another claim unique identifying the user) from the external provider to your client applications. You may want to map that user information with your own unique identification of the user. In that case you would need a persistent user store to hold on to your own unique user identification.

Comment: thanks. One client app needs to store the user information so I'm using ASP.NET Identity to store it, but only in the client DB, not in the Identityserver store. Another client app that will be developed in the near future will not need its own users as all its users will log in via the Belgian eID, which has the Belgian national registry number as primary key (subject claim), which I can use to provide secure access to the data in my API. So basically I'm letting the clients decide if they need a userstore of their own, but as far as I see I don't need one for IdentityServer itself...